# Joining 3 tables and count different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, left-join

I have a query in which I loop through an itemlist(alerts), these alerts have replies which I want to know how many replies that alert/item has, these alerts/items also have some sort of like(interaction) button which I want to know how many people liked it, now I have this query which gives me how many replies I have, but I don't know how I can count how many interactions it has... Could someone take a look at it and maybe help me ?

This is my Query so far:

```
SELECT a.title, a.lat, a.lon, a.alert_content_id, a.date_added, count(*) FROM `alerts` a 
   LEFT JOIN `reply` r ON 
       r.alert_id = a.alerts 
   LEFT JOIN `interactions` i ON 
      i.alert_id = a.alerts 
   GROUP BY a.title, a.lat, a.lon, a.alert_content_id, a.date_added
```

Now this count returns the number of replies, how can I count the number of interactions as well? 
This is what a desired result would look like

```
|a.title|a.lat|a.lon|a.alert_content_id|a.date_added|count(replies)|count(interactions)|
```

count replies is number of rows that `a.alerts == r.alert_id` 
and count interactions is number of rows that `a.alerts == i.alert_id`

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a bit more fidling i found the answer, This returned exactly what i needed.

```
SELECT a.title, a.lat, a.lon, a.alert_content_id, a.date_added, count(r.alert_id) as countRep ,count(i.alert_id) AS countInt 
FROM `alerts` a 
      LEFT JOIN `reply` r ON 
         r.alert_id = a.alerts 
      LEFT JOIN `interactions` i ON 
         i.alert_id = a.alerts 
GROUP BY a.title, a.lat, a.lon, a.alert_content_id, a.date_added
```